# Printing a triangle with incrementing digits instead of asterisks

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I'm experimenting with my program by trying to build different kinds of pyramids and converting the values into different values. I managed to build one with asterisk sign and now I'm trying to find a way on how to change it into running numbers like "0123456789" and the next line is "012345678" and so on. Is there a way to do that without fully/less changes of my code?

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
STAR DB ?
BLANK DB ?
.CODE 

MAIN PROC
      MOV AX,@DATA
      MOV DS,AX

      MOV CX,10
      MOV BH,10
      MOV BL,0

      MOV STAR,BH
      MOV BLANK,BL

      L1:
      CMP BLANK,0
      JE L2

      MOV AH,2
      MOV DL,32
      INT 21H
      DEC BLANK

      JMP L1

      L2:
      MOV AH,2
      MOV DL,'*'
      INT 21H
      DEC STAR
      CMP STAR,0
      JNE L2

      MOV AH,2
      MOV DL,0AH
      INT 21H
      MOV DL,0DH
      INT 21H
      DEC BH    
      MOV STAR,BH
      INC BL    
      MOV BLANK,BL  
      LOOP L1

      EXIT:
      MOV AH,4CH    
      INT 21H

MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: This code works perfectly but doesn't do what you want it to?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to change the asterisk sign into looped printed number like 0123456789 and continue to decrement as it goes down the endpoint of pyramid like 012345678, 01234567, 0123456 upto 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to find a way on how to change it into running numbers like "0123456789" and the next line is "012345678" and so on. **Is there a way to do that without fully/less changes of my code?**

While the other answer provides an alternative solution, my solution  keeps most of your program intact as per request, only adding the digit sequence:

```
L2:
  mov dl, '0'            <--- Setup 1st digit
L3:                      <--- Extra label
  MOV AH,2
  INT 21H
  inc dl                 <--- To next digit
  DEC STAR
  CMP STAR,0             ; Tip: you can remove this instruction 
  JNE L3                 <--- To extra label
```

Expected output (similar to your asterisks):

> ```
> 0123456789
>  012345678
>   01234567
>    0123456
>     012345
>      01234
>       0123
>        012
>         01
>          0
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Consider a simplier algorithm which uses DOS function [Int 21h/AH=09h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) (which displays $-terminated strings). You may shorten the string by overwriting characters at its end with `'$'` in each loop cycle:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
EOL DB 13,10,'$'         ; End of line string.
TXT DB '0123456789$'     ; The initial string.
.CODE 
MAIN PROC
      MOV AX,@DATA
      MOV DS,AX          ; Initialize DS to .DATA segment.   
      MOV AH,9           ; Use DOS function WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT.
      MOV BX,10          ; Initialize the number of iteration (address index).
  L1: MOV DX,OFFSET EOL  
      INT 21H            ; Write EOL first.
      MOV [TXT+BX],'$'   ; Terminate TXT at index BX.
      MOV DX,OFFSET TXT
      INT 21H            ; Write TXT.  
      DEC BX             ; Let BX index the previous character. 
      JNZ L1             ; Loop while BX > 0.
 EXIT:MOV AH,4CH    
      INT 21H
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Result should be this:

```
0123456789
012345678
01234567
0123456
012345
01234
0123
012
01
0
```