# Printing a text triangle pattern using loops in TASM

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-16, tasm

in this exercise it asks to do the following. It's supposed to be run in dosbox and save the code in tasm.

Activity:
Write an assembly language program that will display the following output. Use looping as shown in the video demo.

Mainly from what I understood from the video is use the push, pop, and int 21h for the loop. I based my program on what the prof showed us but the output is different.

```
  A123*B123*C123*


  X

  XX

  XXX

  XXXX

  XXXXX
```

All my attempts ended up in a failure, and it just ended up to nothing.

```
.model small
.stack
.code
main proc
    
    mov cx, 5
    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, 'A'
    int 21h

outer_loop:
    push cx
    push dx
    mov cx, 3
    mov dl, '*'

inner_loop:
    int 21h
    loop inner_loop
    pop dx
    pop cx
    add dl, 2
    loop outer_loop
    mov dl, 13
    int 21h
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
main endp

end main
```

Comment: "ended up to nothing" - I don't know what that means.  Does your code fail to assemble?  Does it assemble but fail to run?  Does it run but not produce the results you intend?  Unless I build your code myself, install dosbox, and attempt to run it, I can't see what's happening.  You need to tell us what's going on.

Comment: Printing character triangles in 16bit code has been asked several times here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65956941/printing-a-triangle-of-characters-in-assembly
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72842431/printing-a-triangle-with-incrementing-digits-instead-of-asterisks/72845679
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76366269/pyramid-in-emu8086-assembly/76387871